# Generate Excel Sheet for search and without search with a single query

Tags: excel, codeigniter-3

I want to generate an excel sheet for all list along with search list so, i have that search in datatables, which is my model

```
public function getAllAdmissions($pdata,$getcount=null)
{
 if(isset($pdata['search_text_1'])!="")
    {
        $this->db->like($search_1[$pdata['search_on_1']], $pdata['search_text_1']); 
    }
    if($getcount)
    {
        return $this->db->select('p.person_id')->from('people as p')->join('people_details as pd','pd.people_id=p.person_id','LEFT')->get()->num_rows();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->select('p.status as status,p.person_id,p.first_name,p.last_name,p.sur_name,pd.father_name as father_name,p.email,p.mobile_number,p.created_on as enroll_date')->from('people as p')->join('people_details as pd','pd.people_id=p.person_id','LEFT');
    }
}
$alladmissions = $query->get()->result_array();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();die();
        foreach($alladmissions as $key=>$values)
        {
            $alladmissions[$key]['sno'] = $generatesno++;
            $alladmissions[$key]['enroll_date'] = date("d M Y",strtotime($alladmissions[$key]['enroll_date']));
            $alladmissions[$key]['admission_date'] = date("d M Y",strtotime($alladmissions[$key]['admission_date']));
        }
    return $alladmissions;
```

which is my controller

```
public function generateexcel()
{
    require_once("PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial')->setSize(10);
        $cols = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
        $c = 0;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cols[$c++]."1", 'S.No');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cols[$c++]."1", 'Date');
        $k = $c++;
        $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
        $objRichText->createText("Students");
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cols[$k]."1")->setValue($objRichText);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cols[$k]."1")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        $k = $c++;
        $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
        $objRichText->createText("Student Details");
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cols[$k]."1")->setValue($objRichText);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cols[$k]."1")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cols[$c++]."1", 'Amount');
        $students = $this->student->getStudents();
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($students); 
        $filename = "students.xls";
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Students');
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"".$filename."\";");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');


}
```

Could anyone help me to how to pass parameters for this cotroller and how to generate excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Export button:

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onClick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')"   title="Export to Excel">Export</button></div><br/>
```

Add id to table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover " border="1" id="testTable" >
```

Add script at below of body:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
              var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
              , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
              , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
              , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
              return function(table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                  var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
              }
            })()</script>
```